# Json Api Auth post request to wordpress backend

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, api

I use json api auth to login from my mobile app into wordpress, it works but when I want to create new post from the app and I do post request it says me the error that I don't have permission; it see me as not logged user, why?

this is my code :

```
app.controller('PostController', function($scope, $http,AuthCookieStorage) {


    var cookie=AuthCookieStorage.get();
    console.log("cookie" + " " + cookie);

    var data={"title":"Hello World!","content_raw":"Content","excerpt_raw":"Excerpt"};

    $scope.register = function() {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://url.com/provawp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      'Authorization' :  cookie
            }
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
            alert("Città aggiunta correttamente!"); 
        }) 
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        }).
        catch(function (error) {
         alert("Errore!");
        console.log("error : " + JSON.stringify(error) );

       }); 
}      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think while passing `Authorization` header you need to prefix token with `Bearer`

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://url.com/provawp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
     data: data,
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + cookie //added 'Bearer '
     }
})
```